# Laravel 'use' all models in a Controller

Tags: laravel-5.4

I am having a utility Controller which need to have access to all the Models in the project. Please explain how should I 'use' all the Models inside a Controller.

Comment: Could you please give more information about how you will use those Models?

Comment: My requirement was to call a specific method in a Model. Since I do not know the Model name in advance, I was thinking how should I get this done. But I decided to use full qualified Model name instead of 'use' statements.

Comment: Since this is not an answer to my question, I am not sure what should I do with this question. Can I 'close' this even w/o an answer?